# rethinkdb frequency of values

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

What is the way to implement a "frequency" query in reThinkDB for some value ?

Example data :

```
[{
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "AAA",
 anotherkey : "BBB"
}, {
 akey : "CCC",
 anotherkey : "CCC"
}]
```

Should yield for `akey` as parameter :

```
{
  "1"   : 2,
  "AAA" : 1,
  "CCC" : 1
}
```

Should yield for `anotherkey` as parameter :

```
{
  "2"   : 2,
  "BBB" : 1,
  "CCC" : 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have an array in a document that looks as your Example data, or does each `{ akey : "1", anotherkey : "2"}` represent a separate document?

Comment: @Tholle those are separate documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
r.expr([{
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "AAA",
 anotherkey : "BBB"
}, {
 akey : "CCC",
 anotherkey : "CCC"
}]).map(function(doc) {
  return r.branch(doc.keys().contains('akey'),{'value': doc('akey')},{})
})
.group('value')
.count()
.ungroup()
.map(function(doc) {
  return r.object(doc('group'), doc('reduction'))
})
.reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.merge(right)
})
```

Another way to do it without `reduce` is:

```
r.expr([{
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "1",
 anotherkey : "2"
}, {
 akey : "AAA",
 anotherkey : "BBB"
}, {
 akey : "CCC",
 anotherkey : "CCC"
}]).map(function(doc) {
  return r.branch(doc.keys().contains('anotherkey'),{'value': doc('anotherkey')},{})
})
.group('value')
.count()
.ungroup()
.map(function(doc) {
  return [doc('group'), doc('reduction')]
})
.coerceTo('object')
```

However, I like `reduce` way because it maps to how I think about the whole process.